# Cambiar posición de dos palabras separadas por un caracter (:) | world:hello --> hello:world

Tags: python, python-3.x

=)

Recientemente me estoy iniciando en Python, estoy intentando crear un script capaz de abrir un archivo (que se encuentra en la misma ruta que el script) y que posteriormente, cree un archivo nuevo con las palabras invertidas. Es decir:

ARCHIVO 1:
world:hello

Este archivo es el archivo primario, que el script debería de abrir y editar.

ARCHIVO 2:
hello:world

Este archivo es el archivo secundario, que el script debería de crear y editar, dejándolo tal y como he puesto anteriormente (hello:world)

He intentado crearlo, pero no consigo que funcione.

Dejo uno de los intentos que he hecho:

```
string = open("combos.txt", "r")
createOut = open("newfile-" + string, "w+")
with open(string) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        with open("newfile-" + string, "a") as out:
            words = string.split(":")
            words = list(reversed(words))
            final = print(":".join(words))
            out.write(final)
print("Done!")
```

Estaré atento a las notificaciones! Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida! =)

Muchisimas gracias por adelantado! Mientras tanto, seguiré investigando! =)

Comment: Buena pregunta, la proxima vez agrega la traza de error, así nos lo pones más fácil a las personas que queremos ayudarte :)

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es buena idea abrir y cerrar los ficheros tantas veces. Es mejor abrirlos al principio y listo. Por otro lado, estabas abriendo un fichero con la variable `string`, que es un fichero en sí. Por otro lado, estabas asignando final a una llamada de print, que devuelve None. Y también puedes aprovecharte del operador [::-1] para invertir la lista.

Así deberías solucionarlo:

```python
with open("combos.txt", "r") as infile:
    with open("newfile-combos.txt", "w") as out:
        for line in infile:
            words = line.split(":")[::-1]
            final = ":".join(words)
            print(final)
            out.write(final)
print("Done!")
```

Comment: Te falto hacer un strip() para sacar el "\n" de la linea leída. También te faltó agregar un "\n" en cada línea del archivo de salida. Debería ser `words=line.strip().split(":")[::-1]` y `out.write(final + "\n")`

Comment: Es cierto! Muchísimas gracias! =) Lo ha solucionado! Aunque no entiendo la función de [::-1], que hace exactamente? Gracias de antemano! Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

=)

Y ahora que lo estaba pensando, para poder reinvertir ese archivo, es decir, de world:hello a hello:world?

Este es el código actual:

```
        with open(combo, "r") as infile:
        with open("newfile-combos.txt", "w") as out:
            for line in infile:
                words = line.strip().split(":")[::-1]
                final = ":".join(words)
                out.write(final + "\n")
    print("Done!")
```

Con esto, para poder reinvertirlo? Como sería? Pensaba que editando el `[::-1]` bastaría pero he visto que no :P

Gracias de antemano! =)